# Import DXF file into PADS Logic

Tags: mentor-pads, dxf

I have a drawing border in DXF format that I need to get into PADS.  Is there a sensible way of doing this, without needing some add-on software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, which was surprisingly easy..

1. Open blank design in PADS Layout
2. Use Drafting Toolbar to import DXF file (I found dxf ver 2000 worked fine)
3. Select layers to import from DXF
4. Highlight entire drawing blank, right click and select Group
5. Select Save to Library

Thanks for your help.

--dave

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The sensible thing to do is to simply draw the page border in the PADS Logic tool using its native commands.

For my applications I have easily been able to make page borders that look just like a clients' existing borders. It can save some time to take one of the supplied PADS borders and modify it into the format that you want.

Comment: that's a good idea, which I will most probably try.  Its a pity that a package like PADS does not offer an easy way of importing such a universal drawing format.